# JFET voltage divider bias calculations

Tags: transistors, voltage-divider, bias, jfet

Hi im having some trouble with knowing how to perform calculations for \$I_D\$ in a simple JFET where it is biased by means of a voltage divider.

I understand that use of the equation:

$$I_D = I_{DSS}\left(1-\frac{V_{GS}}{V_P}\right)^2$$

is needed but because \$I_D\$ is contained within \$V_{GS}\$ (\$V_{GS} = V_G - I_DR_S\$)
I'm not sure about how to go about extracting \$I_D\$.

I understand that you can do so by using a quadratic formula but exactly how I'm not sure.

Could someone help me with a question, say:
\$I_{DSS} = 12\$mA, \$R_S = 1000\Omega\$, \$V_P = -3\$V and \$V_G = 2.5\$V

There is a video on youtube by a guy called rolinychupetin on JFETS and he goes through this example near the end of the video but then just states that \$I_D = 3.81\$mA. I've searched the net for two days now trying to find how he got there to no avail.

Comment: Do you even alge-bra? This is a matter of solving a quadratic equation. First substitute the 2nd equation into the first and reduce it to that form ax^2 + bx + c = 0, where x is Id and a, b, c are do not contain Id. Then solve using the high school method. You can substitute numbers for the symbolic names at any time. Earlier will be less messy, but if you do it at the end, it will give you a general closed-form solution that will work for any set of numbers. You will get two solutions from the quadratic formula, pick the one that makes sense in reality.

Comment: Also note that the value of Vgs is often given, not derived from a formula.  For example you don't usually need to calculate an NPN transistor's Vbe voltage by using other internal parameters.

Answer (score 2):

As you thought, you have to solve quadratic equation to solve this. We know that

$$I_D = I_{DSS}\left(1-\frac{V_{GS}}{V_P}\right)^2\tag1$$

We also know that,

$$V_{GS} = V_{G}-I_DR_S\tag2$$

Substituting (2) in (1) and simplifying will produce a quadratic equation like this:

$$aI_D^2 + bI_D + c = 0$$

Solve this [quadratic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) to get the value for \$I_D\$.

From the two solutions you get, *pick the one that makes sense in reality* as Spehro Pefhany commented.

Comment: sorry to ask such a simple question. thanks for the reply though. i keep trying it but cant get it to work to be 3.81ma, must be a mix up in my calculation somewhere.

Comment: \$I_D=3.81mA\$ satisfies that quadratic equation. So solving the equation will result in that value. Keep trying.

Comment: figured it out in the end. i had a minus sign wrong further up in the calculations and it completely screwed the rest of the figures further on. haha - feel so stupid now. thanks again